# How to handle current logged user as author properly when base django user model is overwriten?

Tags: python, django

Here is the deal:

**users/models.py** (*here I overwrite based django model*):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.


    class ProfileUser(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        profile_image = models.URLField()

        @receiver(post_save, sender=User) # Still don't know how, but next rows create ProfileUser when User is created
        def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
            if created:
                ProfileUser.objects.create(user=instance)

        @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
        def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
            instance.profileuser.save()

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.user}"
```

And using (for example when I add objects (posts)) **objects/views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views import generic
from objects.models import Object, ProfileUser
from .forms import ObjectForm, CommentForm
from django.contrib import messages


class UserObjectsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'user_objects.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return Object.objects.filter(author_id = user_id)


def add_object(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.info(request, 'За да добавите нов Обект, трябва да сте регистриран потребител!')
        return redirect('account_login')
    form = ObjectForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.author = ProfileUser.objects.get(user=request.user)
        obj.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Успешно добавихте нов Обект, може да видите вашите обекти във вашия профил!')
        return redirect('home')

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, "add_object.html", context)

def show_object(request, pk):
    obj = Object.objects.get(id=pk)

    context = {
        'object': obj
    }

    return render(request, "show_object.html", context)

def add_comment_to_object(request, pk):
    obj = Object.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.object = obj
        user = request.user
        author = ProfileUser.objects.get(user=user)
        comment.author = author
        comment.save()
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, 'add_comment.html', context)
```

As you can see I'm also using these rows to get current user:

```
obj.author = ProfileUser.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

**But I'm not quite sure, this is the right way?**

Comment: What is your question exactly? What are you trying to achieve and what is going wrong with your current code?

Comment: @Vincent There is no error. I'm curious if this is the right way, or there is a better way to do it.

Comment: It's the right way. What you could do is adding some 'security' to your code. For example. What happens if a ProfileUser is not found by the current user. You could use a try, except block for that. In addition, is a ProfileUser always created for the logged in user? If not, you could use a get_or_create method for the ProfileUser instance.